# The motivation behind the discovery of solutions of linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I'm gonna give a lecture about analysis and solutions of linear systems with $n$ variables, I would like to know what are the most interesting examples I could use in my lecture. The lecture will be given to under-graduation students.

Comment: I recommend Thirty-Three Miniatures: Mathematical Applications of Linear Algebra, by Jiri Matousek.